# Inserción de Dependencias C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

hola gente como están me gustaría explicarles una consulta que tengo más teórica porque el código funciona bien, yo estoy trabajando con inyección de dependencias, **SOY NOVATA**.

donde en el archivo program.cs tengo todos los servicios y sobre todo tengo esto

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICliente, ServioCliente>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProducto, ServicioProducto>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProvedor, ServicioProvedor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITours, ServicioTours>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFacturacion, ServicioFacturacion>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(option =>
    {
        option.LoginPath = "/Login/Validar";
        option.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1000);
        option.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Privacy";
    });


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

pero tengo la duda de que cuando uno lee por ejemplo este link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siempre se muestran ejemplos con una sola interfaz.

Pero realmente está bien tener esto de una forma?

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICliente, ServioCliente>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProducto, ServicioProducto>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProvedor, ServicioProvedor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITours, ServicioTours>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFacturacion, ServicioFacturacion>();
```

qué pasa si me código llega a tener 20 interfaces de 20 servicios diferentes en el archivo programan.cs siempre me tocara estar agregando uno por uno, no existe una forma de hacer 1 solo y que me los reconozca a todos?

**Básicamente esa es mi duda, existe alguna forma mucho más rápida de yo hacer un solo builder.Services.AddScoped<IMaestra, ServicioMaestro>();**

el problema es que si yo digo agregando servicios de la misma forma como menciono que pasa si llego a ocupar 20 interfaces, me toca siempre estar una por una agregándola, pero nose si allá una forma mucho más facil de hacerlo.

Comment: _no existe una forma de hacer 1 solo y que me los reconozca a todos_ >> Dale una mirada a [Autofac](https://autofac.org/), tiene mejoras en vez de utilizar el que viene por default con .NET, tiene [buena ayuda para varias formas de registrar nuestros objectos/clases](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html). Iincluso en el home puedas ver que puedas "buscar" en los assemblies para inyectar los que tiene interfaces que terminen con empiencen con "Repository..." (por ejemplo). Dale una mirada

Answer (score 1):

Debo admitir que hay aspectos teóricos de tu pregunta que no entiendo. No entiendo la necesidad de crear tantos servicios junto con sus interfaces.

Veo siempre en este y otros sitios una sobreexplotación de capas de abstracción y granularidad, porque teóricamente es bueno y porque todos los ejemplos de 2 líneas se ven geniales, en muchos casos la realidad práctica golpea fuertemente esos escenarios y quizás eso es lo que te está pasando a ti.

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera:

- Tengo mi `DbContext` en el cual están los `DbSet` que representan las tablas
- Agrego el servicio `builder.Services.AddDbContext<MiContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Key")));`
- Y luego en los `Controllers` inyecto `public ComprasController(MiContext context)`

No hay capa de servicios, no hay DTO, ni repositorios mas allá del propio DbContext y me funciona perfecto

Pero digamos que no quieres seguir esta recomendación porque en el libro del autor YoNuncaHeDesarrolladoAlgoReal dice que no se recomienda

Buen, pero tampoco es necesario crear todas las interfaces, en mi opinión tener una interfaz con una clase en una relación 1 a 1 es solo trabajar de más.

**¿Para que se usan las interfaces en este caso?**

Estas interfaces te permiten abstraerte de la implementación (la clase), en general es para hacer pruebas, así tu puedes tener otra implementación con fines de testing. En mi experiencia, lo mejor es tener una base de datos de pruebas y cambias el `connectionstring` y sería. Con lo cual te ahorras las 20 interfaces que señalas
*(obviamente hablando de los servicios que conectan con una base de datos)*

Ahora quizás el Youtuber TengoUnAñoDeExperienciaYMeCreoSenior puede discrepar conmigo, entonces te propongo la siguiente alternativa

Tu has creado la siguiente nomenclatura

- Los servicios tienen en su nombre el prefijo `Servicio` ej: `ServicioPersonas`
- Las interfaces tienen el prefijo `I` ej: `IPersonas`

Entonces no hay más que buscar en el ensamblado las interfaces y clases que cumplan la condición

```
private const String PREFIX = "Servicio";
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
    //buscamos las clases que comiencen con el "Servicio"
    var servicios = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(a => a.Name.StartsWith(PREFIX));
    foreach (var clase in servicios)
    {
        //buscamos la interfaz que le corresponde
        var LaInterface = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == "I" + clase.Name.Replace(PREFIX, ""));
        if(LaInterface == null) //si no tiene interfaz lo agregamos sin ella
        {
            builder.Services.AddScoped(clase);
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Services.AddScoped(LaInterface, clase);
        }
                
    }
    var app = builder.Build();

   //ETC
```

A mi no me gusta esta solución porque depende de una nomenclatura a partir de los nombres de clases e interfaces. Yo te insto a que des un paso atrás y pienses si realmente 20 servicios son necesarios o si quizás estas subdividiendo todo en una granularidad demasiado fina

---

**Update**

Para solventar el problema de depender de una nomenclatura de los nombres también podrías crear un `CustomAttibute` de esta manera

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple =false)]
    public class InyectameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type? Interface { get; set; } = null;
    public InyectameAttribute(Type Interface) => this.Interface = Interface;
    public InyectameAttribute() { }
}
```

Aquí le pasamos la interface como argumento. Podríamos haber sacado la interface correspondiente directamente desde la clase, pero una clase puede tener varias interfaces por lo que hay que identificarla

En cada clase pondrías:

```
[Inyectame(typeof(IPersona))]
public class ServicioPersona : IPersona
{

}
```

Y luego en el Program.cs algo similar a lo anterior

```
var servicios = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(a => a.CustomAttributes.Any(b => b.AttributeType == typeof(InyectameAttribute)));
           
foreach (var clase in servicios)
{
    var Atributto = clase.GetCustomAttribute<InyectameAttribute>();
    if (Atributto?.Interface == null)
    {
        builder.Services.AddScoped(clase);
    }
    else
    {
        builder.Services.AddScoped(Atributto.Interface, clase);
    }
                
}
```

Evidentemente esto funciona para los clases que están en el mismo proyecto, si tu tienes proyectos separados que originan otras dll's debes cargarlos con `Assembly.LoadFrom`